# Get a post id to view that separately from the Facebook wall

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an application where I want to show the content of a post I have in my wall.

I have the post_id, but how do I know how to show the comments and content of the post?

Answer (score 1):

If you get the JSON response for that particular post

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/post_id
```

there is an "actions" object, that contains a "comment" and "like" actions.

This also contains all the information you are after, the "message" object being the post message and a "comments" object containing an array of all comments. You just need to inspect the various properties and use their values.

Is that what you are after?

You can see a response on *[Graph API explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)* by entering your post_id (you will need to grant the explorer application the correct permissions).